# Storing object inside a variable from API javascript

Tags: javascript, api, url

I am trying to store the JSON objects that is returned from a API. I am storing the object in a variable called obj however I can't figure out  why I am unable to use that variable in a function to retrieve certain properties of that object.

```
var obj;

btn_top.addEventListener("click", function () {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => obj = data)
    .then(() => console.log(obj))
  var profit = [];
  console.log("testing");
  console.log(obj);
  Object.values(obj).forEach(e=> {
    var eProfit = e.sell_average;
    profit.push(eProfit);
  });
  console.log(profit);
});
```

I get the following error.

```
main.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I am able to properly return the obj when using

```
.then(() => console.log(obj))
```

however after that I get the errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Try like this way .then((obj)=> console.log(obj))

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is undefined because the logging and `forEach` loop is executed **before** the Promise is resolved and `obj` is assigned to be the resulting data from the Promise call.

When you're dealing with Promises (i.e. asynchronous code) you need to execute all data manipulation in the `then()` block.

Answer (score 0):

How can you do that!
Fetch is asynchrone, please read the doc!

the next lines after

> .then(() => console.log(obj))

Are not running when the fetch is ending, but before.

Your "next" code has to be inside the last Fetch callback :

```
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(jsonData=> {
        let profit = [];
        Object.values(jsonData).forEach(e=> {
          var eProfit = e.sell_average;
          profit.push(eProfit);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using **async functions**. The code is much cleaner and easier to understand.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function